# Who is the Lord of Godsgrace?

Tags: a-song-of-ice-and-fire

In Chapter 38 of A Dance With Dragons, "The Watcher" (Areo Hotah's POV), Areo notes the following:

> The white knight [Ser Balon Swann] did drink, as was only courteous. His companions likewise. So did the Princess Arianne, Lady Jordayne, the **Lord of Godsgrace**...

Godsgrace is held by House Allyrion, and House Allyrion is ruled by *Lady* Delonne Allyrion. I've checked [the chapter summary](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/A_Dance_with_Dragons-Chapter_38) on AWOIAF, and there is no linked page for "The Lord of Godsgrace"

Who could Areo be referring to?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the related page on the [Wiki of Ice and Fire](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/House_Allyrion), we see that the current Lord of Godsgrace is [Lady Delonne Allyrion](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Delonne_Allyrion).

We don't know much about Delonne, (besides that she is the Lady of Godsgrace and the head of House Allyrion) just that she has a son named [Ryon Allyrion](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Ryon_Allyrion) (from AFFC Appendix) and a bastard grandson named [Ser Daemon Sand](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Daemon_Sand) (A Storm of Swords, Chapter 38, Tyrion) also known as the Bastard of Godsgrace. The Lady could just be acting as Lord, since her Lord died/vanished/whatever.

Comment: I've acknowledged Lady Allyrion in my OP. Do you have any inklings as to who Areo could be referring to given that there is no *Lord* of Godsgrace? Is this likely to be a simple mistake by GRRM?

Comment: If you see the right part of the Wiki page, you'll see  `Current Lord:  Lady Delonne Allyrion`. Apart from that, no I haven't seen any mention of GRRM concerning this

Comment: I did notice, but I thought that was just a quirk of AWOIAF. Do characters in canon ever refer to female heads of Houses as "Lords"?

Comment: To be honest, I don't think so. But anything can happen in a fantasy world. The Lady could just be acting as Lord, since her Lord died/vanished/whatever.

Comment: Trivia: Just yesterday when reading AFFC, I noted that princess Arianne Martell claimed to have lost her virginity to the Bastard of Godsgrace.

Answer (score 2):

Lady Delonne Allyrion is listed along with other Lords in the [Appendix of AFFC](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/A_Feast_for_Crows-Appendix#House_Martell):

> Prince Doran's bannermen, the Lords of Dorne:
>
> ...
>
> - Delonne Allyrion, Lady of Godsgrace

Even if her official title is not "Lord" presumably she is in effect an "acting" Lord as the (unmarried) head of House Allyrion.